# What is good practise map.remove and put value or just override the existing value

Tags: java

I really want to know . If we remove a key from a map and add a same key is a good practice or just overriding the same key in a map is a good practice.

Example if i have a key named k then

map.remove("k");

map.put("k", "value");

is a good practice

or

map.put("K", "value");

is a good practice.

Comment: Both do the same thing. Then less number of step is better,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `put()`. Less step is better. Also, using `remove` first is useless if the key is not yet in the `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

In my view the good practice is to use -:
**map.put**

as if the key is already existing the put method will simply override the old value with the new value and return the old value. There is no need to remove the key.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(receivedKey, receivedValue);
```

Oracle documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V)